# why jquery done() showing success result multiple time instead of one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am processing my html form with jquery / ajax request. It's calling by jquery 'change()'. So when request is success it's showing me success result which is

**Successfully Updated**

Well, but if it again request it's showing

**Successfully UpdatedSuccessfully Updated**

It's just added last success result text to new one. I want to show only onnce. Can you tell me why it's happening ?

**my code:**

```
$("#corp_www_eng, #domestic_www_japaness").change(function(){

var cid =  $("#cid").val();
var corp_www_eng =  $("#corp_www_eng").val();
var domestic_www_japaness =  $("#domestic_www_japaness").val();     


$.ajax({
  url: 'edit_companyinfo.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'html',
  data: {
      "cid" : cid,
      "corp_www_eng" : corp_www_eng,
      "domestic_www_japaness" : domestic_www_japaness,          
      },
}).done(function ( data ) {

  $('#result').append(data);
  $('#result').show();
  $('#result').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');    

});

});
```

Comment: Can you say what _#corp_www_eng, #domestic_www_japaness_ elements are and **WHEN** do you want the data in those elements to be submitted via ajax (i mean exactly on which event)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting `.html()` for `.append()`

```
$("#result").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I  believe it is because your are appending the data to the #result div. You could try adding

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '';
```

This would clear that div of any content before appending the new content.